# How to add a Payara server instance to a deployment group created from another machine?

Tags: payara

I have three different windows machines running in the cloud. Each machine has the same version of Payara Server (5.2021.9) running on it. One is supposed to act like DAS -> create deployment groups and manage it, the other ones are supposed to act like nodes in the deployment groups. I created the deployment group on one machine, but I cannot add the server instances running on those other machines to this deployment group (No option to configure hostname or ipaddress).

I am learning deployment groups in Payara Server (Community Edition:5.2021.9). I want to achieve load balancing for my JSF 2.1 web application, so I am fiddling around with deployment groups.
I went through the technical documentation on deployment groups, and created one from the Payara admin console. Now, I want to add another remote server instance to this deployment group which is running in separate windows box. I could not find anything on the admin console to configure hostname or ip address while adding a new instance to the deployment group. The documentation on Payara Website for 5.2021.9 (Community) also does not have any asadmin commands to do this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?